# always YES?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

`[NSThread isMultiThreaded]` always returns `YES` for my iPhone application, both in simulator and on the device, even if I run it first thing in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

It this expected?

(I'm using Snow Leopard, if it makes a difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally normal. It's almost always true for Mac apps as well, unless you create a command-line application that doesn't use AppKit.

In particular, Core Animation, Core Audio, and possibly some other parts of Cocoa will spawn background threads on you behalf.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that UIView layer compositing and animation is done in a thread (spawned by Cocoa).